# Single Board Computer with OpenCL?

Tags: parallel-processing, raspberry-pi, opencl

first of all, this is my first question here. So please let me know if I can improve it :)

I am currently developing a application, where i need to read sensors over I2C and do some massive calculations afterwards. All of this shouldn't need more than about 10 -30 ms.

Currently we are using a Raspberry Pi. However, we already reached it's the limit of its capabilities and we aren't even near our expected results.

This is why we are looking for a different SBC with GPU support for parallel computing of thousands of values (more specific: discrete 3D-convolution), which supports

- Python
- I2C/SPI
- C++
- OpenCL / CUDA / ...

Also it would be perfect, if there was some community to ask, if i have problems.

Do you know any Singe Board Computer, that satisfies these conditions?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: SP doesn't do recommendations.  The only improvement I can think of would be to remove the question.  Then spend a few minutes reading through the material in the help centre to understand that any hate your question attracts is not at the expense of the love we extend to new players in the SO game.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use OpenCL on the Raspberry Pi with the VC4CL library, although I believe it's not 100% complete yet.

If you are convinced you need another SBC, I've heard good things about Asus's Tinkerboard.
**https://www.asus.com/Single-Board-Computer/Tinker-Board/**